# InsecurePlatformWarning al usar pip en Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, pip, ubuntu, python-2.7

Estoy observando un mensaje de alerta (no es un error) `InsecurePlatformWarning` al ejecutar el comando `pip` en Linux:

```
$ pip search reportlab
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90:
         InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available.
         This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail.
         For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
reportlab           - The ReportLab Toolkit
```

Tengo instalada la última versión de `pip`:

```
$ pip show pip
---
Metadata-Version: 2.0
Name: pip
Version: 7.1.2
Summary: The PyPA recommended tool for installing Python packages.
Home-page: https://pip.pypa.io/
Author: The pip developers
Author-email: python-virtualenv@groups.google.com
License: MIT
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires:
```

Estoy usando Python 2.7.6.

En versiones anteriores no me mostraba este mensaje. Entiendo que me está indicando que mi plataforma es insegura, ¿cómo o qué tengo que instalar para evitar recibir esta alerta?

**Actualización:**

Ya tengo instalada la última versión de PyOpenSSL:

```
$ pip show pyOpenSSL
---
Metadata-Version: 1.0
Name: pyOpenSSL
Version: 0.13
Summary: Python wrapper module around the OpenSSL library
Home-page: http://pyopenssl.sourceforge.net/
Author: Jean-Paul Calderone
Author-email: exarkun@twistedmatrix.com
License: APL2
Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires:
```

Si intento instalar `request[security]` me da el siguiente mensaje:

```
$ pip install 'request[security]'
requests 2.2.1 does not provide the extra 'security'
```

Comment: ¿Se soluciona si instalas el paquete `requests[security]`? --> `pip install 'requests[security]'`

Comment: ¿Has probado a realizar alguna de las dos acciones indicadas en https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning ?

Comment: @fedorqui me sale `requests 2.2.1 does not provide the extra 'security'`

Comment: Indica por favor qué versión de Python estás usando. ¿2.7, 2.6, 3.X?

Comment: @fedorqui ya actualicé la pregunta

Comment: La alternativa parece ser `pip install pyopenssl ndg-httpsclient pyasn1`, sacado de [InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29202163/1983854).

Comment: @fedorqui funciono! Ya tenia instalado el `pyOpenSSL`, parece que los otros paquetes eran lo que faltaban. Conviertele en respuesta para aceptarla!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sub>Respondo tras consultar la [respuesta equivalente en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29202163/1983854) y "debugar" en los comentarios</sub>

Simplemente debes instalar los paquetes de seguridad:

```
pip install requests[security]
```

o instalarlos directamente:

```
pip install pyopenssl ndg-httpsclient pyasn1
```

Si en Ubuntu tienes problemas instalando `pyopenssl`, deberás instalar también las siguientes dependencias:

```
apt-get install libffi-dev libssl-dev
```

Comment: Me funcionó la segunda opción, gracias!